# How do I turn down volume at lock screen?

Tags: windows-7, audio

Its early in the morning and I have a program that makes alot of noise at startup. I heard the startup sound pretty loud, I cant turn off volume, or how. Dont want to wait 'till later. I tested with the make your computer easier to use thing to see the sound. Tryed 
shortcuts and some other stuff, I don't think you can do anything.  :(

EDIT: Windows 7 Profesional... woops.

Comment: Can't you change the program to stop making that sound?

Answer (score 0):

Press the mute button if you have laptop/notebook quickly and if you have desktop computer, then put the sound pin off :D :P